# how to have only one Pod created for/by Cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob, kyma

I am running this Cronjob at 2 AM in the morning:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: postgres-backup
spec:
  # Backup the database every day at 2AM
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: postgres-backup
            image: postgres:10.4
            command:
            - "/bin/sh"
            - -c
            - |
              pg_dump -Fc -d postgresql://$DBUSER:$DBPASS@$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBNAME > /var/backups/backup_$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M").bak;
            env:
            - name: DBHOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: dev-db-config
                  key: db_host
            - name: DBPORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: dev-db-config
                  key: db_port
            - name: DBNAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: dev-db-config
                  key: db_name
            - name: DBUSER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: dev-db-secret
                  key: db_username
            - name: DBPASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: dev-db-secret
                  key: db_password
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/backups
              name: postgres-backup-storage
          - name: postgres-restore
            image: postgres:10.4
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/backups
              name: postgres-backup-storage
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: postgres-backup-storage
            hostPath:
            # Ensure the file directory is created.
              path: /var/volumes/postgres-backups
              type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

The jobs are getting executed successfully, but what I don't like is that for every Job execution a new Pod is created:

[image: Multiple Pods of Cornjob Job execution]

Is there a way to clean previous (old) created Pods?
Or maybe is there a way to rerun one an the same Pod/Job every time?

Answer (score 3):

If only last job and pod need to be preserved, you can use `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` field set to `1`.

This way only last job and corresponding pod will be preserved. By default it's set to `3`. Also it's possible to set this value to `0` and nothing will be saved after cronjob's execution.

Same logic has `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` field, it has `1` by default.

See [jobs history limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits).

---

This is how it looks when I get events from cronjob:

```
$ kubectl describe cronjob test-cronjob
...
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age    From                Message
  ----    ------            ----   ----                -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  2m31s  cronjob-controller  Created job test-cronjob-27304493
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   2m30s  cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: test-cronjob-27304493, status: Complete
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  91s    cronjob-controller  Created job test-cronjob-27304494
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   90s    cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: test-cronjob-27304494, status: Complete
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  90s    cronjob-controller  Deleted job test-cronjob-27304493
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  31s    cronjob-controller  Created job test-cronjob-27304495
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   30s    cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: test-cronjob-27304495, status: Complete
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  30s    cronjob-controller  Deleted job test-cronjob-27304494
```

Only one last job is presented:

```
$ kubectl get jobs
NAME                    COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
test-cronjob-27304496   1/1           1s         3s
```

And one pod:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
test-cronjob-27304496-r4qd8        0/1     Completed   0          38s
```

Comment: This solution looks like the most viable option to my problem. However I've noticed that my Job never completes nor fails, as the Pod is always in "NotReady" status. This happens because the "postgres-backup" container gets terminated after execution, because it get successfully completed. Do you know, is there a way to "manually" set the readiness of a container?

Comment: @f.bele Well, I've noticed based on labels you have `istio` and I tried to use it with `istio` and got the same result. What happens is pod is created, istio sidecar is injected, container with `postrgres` completed but `istio` sidecar container is still running. This is why pod is `notReady`. One of the options can be avoiding injecting `istio` sidecar container to the pods created by jobs. Can be done with `template.metadata.annotations` in cronjob with `sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"` value. So at this point the question is about 'how to deal with istio"

Comment: you are right, we use `istio`. I tried your solution, the full path where I put your solution is `spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.metadata.annotations` and then the value you suggested `sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"`. unfortunately after this the Pod crashes and terminates immediately but the Job still remains there.

Comment: I suggest [asking another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224) since it's a completely different questions. Only 1 job and corresponding pod will be preserved with this setup. As for jobs completion with istio, you need to provide all details: istio version used, job spec (you can start with [simple test cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#example)), logs, events, everything that will help to understand why it happens this way. Because in my test stand on GKE this option works correctly, no sidecar is injected to that pod.

Comment: See [the 5th point](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/injection/#the-result-of-sidecar-injection-was-not-what-i-expected). This is how it's supposed to be. + other potential options to check. It can be other dependencies or istio config which we have no idea about.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set `ttlSecondsAfterFinished`, to find out more try:

```
kubectl explain cronjob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished --api-version=batch/v1beta1
```

> ttlSecondsAfterFinished limits the lifetime of a Job that has finished
> execution (either Complete or Failed). If this field is set,
> ttlSecondsAfterFinished after the Job finishes, it is eligible to be
> automatically deleted. When the Job is being deleted, its lifecycle
> guarantees (e.g. finalizers) will be honored. If this field is unset, the
> Job won't be automatically deleted. If this field is set to zero, the Job
> becomes eligible to be deleted immediately after it finishes. This field is
> alpha-level and is only honored by servers that enable the TTLAfterFinished
> feature.

Shortly, the `Job` created by `CronJob` will be deleted after specified seconds.

---

In your case:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: postgres-backup
spec:
  # Backup the database every day at 2AM
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 60 # after 1 minute the job and the pods will be deleted by kubernetes
...
```

Please note, that `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` will be applied iff the job was terminated successfully.

Comment: This would have been a great solution as it also cleans the Job itself, however the feature is only available on Kubernetes v1.21 onwards and it is still in beta, and I am unfortunately working on older version than that.

Comment: Interesting, I use it on v1.15.11 and it works, probably TTL controller is installed on our cluster.

Comment: But does it delete the Job or only the Pod, but the Job remains?

Comment: AFAIK, it deletes the job and the pod. CronJob remains, of course

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this

**First method, with the job spec**

add a `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` field of the Job to a number of seconds. The activeDeadlineSeconds applies to the duration of the job

Once a Job reaches activeDeadlineSeconds, all of its running Pods are terminated and the Job status will become type: Failed with reason: DeadlineExceeded.

Set the activeDeadlineSeconds to be much longer than the expected running time

**Second method, with the pod**

make the pod so that it terminates itself when the job is complete.  Something like altering the command to

```
pg_dump -Fc -d postgresql://$DBUSER:$DBPASS@$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBNAME > /var/backups/backup_$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M").bak; exit
```

Comment: This solution does clean/delete the Pod, but the Job still remains. Is there a way to delete the Job itself? Because when the Job is deleted, all dependent Pods get also deleted automatically.